# Are constant references still best practice in c++11 and later?

Tags: c++11, reference, constants, pass-by-const-reference

I recently read an article about the new move semantics in C++. It was about the confusion how to best implement a return value for a large object. The conclusion was, just implement it like return by copy and let the compiler decide if a move works best.

Now I wondered if this is true for function parameters as well meanwhile.

Currently I use const references like this:

```
void setLargeObject(const LargeObject &obj) {
     _obj = obj;
}
```

Instead of the simple copy:

```
void setLargeObject(LargeObject obj) {
     _obj = obj;
}
```

**Are parameters, to copy large objects, passed by const reference still be the best practice in C++11 and later?**

Comment: I do believe so, a reference is weightless compared to a large object.

Comment: I think it's easy for the compiler to know that the value being returned can be moved (esp if it's a local variable about to go out of scope). I don't think it's so easy for it to know that about parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If setting the property requires taking ownership of the value, then pass by value. It will be copied if necessary before the function call, when the parameter is initialized. Inside the function, move it into place.

```
void setLargeObject(LargeObject obj) {
     _obj = std::move(obj);
}
```

If `LargeObject` doesn't support move semantics (so having `std::move` changes nothing), then you might use `const&` to limit the performance hit to one copy instead of two. However, the best solution is to add movability, not to stay with `const&`.